# Order of average of $\mathcal{O}_p(1)$ random variables

Tags: probability

Consider a random variable $\mathbf{X} \in R^n$. Let $X_i$ denote the $i$-th element of $\mathbf{X}$. Suppose that $\mathbf{X} = \mathcal{O}_p(1)$ elementwise (i.e. $X_i$ is stochastically bounded or $X_i = \mathcal{O}_p(1)$ for $i = 1, \ldots, n)$ and that $\mathbb{E}[X_i^2] < C$ for $i = 1, \ldots, n$. Based on this, is it possible to show that the average of the elements of $\mathbf{X}$ is also stochastically bounded, i.e.

$$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^n X_i = \mathcal{O}_p(1)?$$

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\{X_i\}$ are i.i.d. with $\mathsf{E}X_1=+\infty$, then
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\to+\infty \quad\text{a.s.}
$$
(See, e.g., Corollary 3 [here](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-mathematical-statistics/volume-41/issue-4/The-Limit-Points-of-a-Normalized-Random-Walk/10.1214/aoms/1177696894.full).)

---

If $A\equiv\sup_{i\ge 1}\mathsf{E}|X_i|<\infty$, then for any $C>0$,
$$
\mathsf{P}(|\bar{X}_n|>C)\le \frac{A}{C}.
$$
Now, choose $C$ s.t. $A/C$ is small.

Comment: Good point! I've edited the question to assume that the first two moments are bounded. Thanks!

Comment: @user304347 It would be better if you asked a separate question instead of editing the original question.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I'll make a separate question next time.

Comment: @user304347 The reason is that the first part of the answer looks now unrelated to the question :)

Comment: Nice solution! Just using Markov and other simple inequalities... Thanks again!